# Why is it outputting 5 when it should output 4

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am giving it the argument (Hi this is Michael). But it outputs
String '1' - 'Hi'
String '2' - 'this'
String '3' - 'is'
String '4' - 'Michael'
Total number of strings: 5
When it should say the total number of strings is 4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* print a given string and a number in a pre-determined format. */
void
print_string(int num, char* string)
{
    printf("String '%d' - '%s'\n", num, string);
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;

    /* check for command line arguments */
    if (argc < 2) { /* 2 - 1 for program name (argv[0]) and one for a param. */
        printf("Usage: %s [<string> ...]\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }

    /* loop over all strings, print them one by one */
    for (argc--, argv++, i = 1; argc > 0; argc--, argv++, i++) {
        print_string(i, argv[0]);  /* function call */
    }

    printf("Total number of strings: %d\n", i);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only loop while `argc > 0` ... you're missing one...

Comment: It outputs the value it's supposed to output :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how the "for" loop works. Each time you iterate through the loop, it increments i first (i++) before checking the exit condition of the loop (argc > 0).

So when you start with i = 1, this is what happens:

- It prints "Hi", increments i to 2, then checks if argc > 0, check
  passes
- It prints "this", increments i to 3, then checks if argc > 0,
  check passes
- It prints "is", increments i to 4, then checks if argc >
  0, check passes
- It prints "Michael", increments i to 5, then checks
  if argc > 0, **check fails, so we exit the loop**.

So by the time we reach the final print, i is equal to 5.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see 5, not 4, is because you start `i` at `1`, not at `0`, and it gets incremented in the `for` loop:

```
for (argc--, argv++, i = 1; argc > 0; argc--, argv++, i++) {
    //                                                ^^^
}
```

After `String 4` gets printed in the final iteration, the loop counter gets incremented one final time, yielding `5` for the next printout.